# Rollbar Error processing the item: Net::OpenTimeout, execution expired

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rollbar

I hope is not a duplicated question, but I haven't been able to find anything.
I used to include Rollbar as standard error-tracking tool in my projects. I'm using it succesfully in various different places. But I have a problem with one...

I don't know why, but in a specific, company server I get always `[Rollbar] Error processing the item: Net::OpenTimeout, execution expired.`
And of course I don't receive anything in my Rollbar account

Executing `rake rollbar:test` I get this error

> /app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rollbar-2.15.0/lib/rollbar/delay/thread.rb:58:in `rescue in block in configure_exit_handler': unable to reap all threads within 3 seconds (Rollbar::Delay::Thread::TimeoutError) from .../app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rollbar-2.15.0/lib/rollbar/delay/thread.rb:52:in block in configure_exit_handler

As it is successfully working in another server I guess is something related to this specific machine.. but what? 
It doesn't work synchronously neither asynchronously. And the problems occurs only in this server.

Is not a DNS problem (I'm using the Google's ones).
Is not a permission problem because I receive a response from  `curl https://api-alt.rollbar.com/api/1/item/` so.. I have no idea..

I'm using rails 4.2.5.1 and Rollbar 2.15 (but I tried wiith a downgraded version and the problem persists)

Thank you for any idea!

**EDIT**

It seems is really a server issue. But System department is not able to solve it. A solution could be increatse the Net::OpenTimeOut waiting time but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Hey there - I'm a member of the Rollbar support team, and we'd be glad to help you out.  I checked our system and couldn't find your username or email address.  Do you mind forwarding this question to support@rollbar.com?  We provide support to all users and have team members in Europe, so we'll be able to work with you through this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the way to make it work. My final configuration is

```
  Rollbar.reconfigure do |config|
      config.access_token = ENV['ROLLBAR_TOKEN']
      config.open_timeout = 15
      config.request_timeout = 15

      if %w(test development).include?(Rails.env)
          config.enabled = false
      end
  end
```

the trick is to use `reconfigure` instead of `configure` otherwise it will not override the timeouts!